# How is a DLL of the wrong bitness handled during loading?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll, 32bit-64bit, loadlibrary

Disclaimer: I know you cannot load a DLL of the wrong bitness. The question here is what happens when one is encountered.

**What happens when a 32bit / 64bit Windows process encounters a 64bit / 32bit DLL during [searching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications) for a module during DLL load?**

**And by "what happens" I mean what dance *exactly* is the NT DLL loader performing.**

Is there any difference between 32 -> 64 bit and 64 -> 32 bit?

Note: I think the answer should be independet on whether the (native) DLL is loaded dynamically via [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) or "statically" via link-time dependency.

My tests:

#### Scenario 0:

```
...\harry.exe
- no further files, but `harry.exe` needs `sally.dll`
```

In principle easy - can't load.
My `LoadLibrary` call sets error [`ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`/126](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) is this case.

Scenario 1:

```
...\harry.exe ~ (a. 64 bit / b. 32 bit) 
...\sally.dll ~ (a. 32 bit / b. 64 bit)
```

- that is, the DLL is present, but in the wrong bitness.

This will (in both cases a. and b.) set error `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`/193 from `LoadLibrary`.
Now it gets interesting:

Scenario 2.a: (invert the bitness for b.)

```
set PATH=...\x86;...\x64;%PATH%
...\harry64.exe (depends on sally.dll in 64 bit)
...\x86\sally.dll
...\x64\sally.dll
```

- that is, we have the executable and the DLL in both versions. *And* the executable can find the DLL of the correct bitness. **But** it will find the DLL of the *wrong* bitness first.

My result: *This simply works.*

When running in the VS 2015 debugger, I can see in this case:

```
'harry.exe' (Win32): Loaded '...\x86\sally.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'harry.exe' (Win32): Unloaded '...\x86\sally.dll'
'harry.exe' (Win32): Loaded '...\x64\sally.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

-> success

So, win-win, as long as the DLL of the correct bitness *can* be found it will be found.

The problems I have here:

- Both me and a co-worker always though this didn't work, namely that Windows would stop trying once it found the DLL with the wrong bitness.

  - Therefore: Has this always been the case?
- Obviously, the loader is doing *something* with the wrong-bitness DLL -- does this "probing" have any side-effects? (apart from possibly slower load times.)
- Is this bloody documented somewhere? (gotta love MSDN :-)

---

Test Notes: Tests for this post done on a Win10/x64 with Visual Studio 2015. Results on a Win7/x64 were the same though.

Comment: `Has this always been the case?` - yes. even in 2003 x64 (or xp x64). `ZwMapViewOfSection` return `STATUS_IMAGE_MACHINE_TYPE_MISMATCH` in case mismatch 32/64 bit. loader check this code and if yes continue search. only if your exe marked as for NT 3.x and below will be exception. fanny that this check (for `MajorSubsystemVersion <= 3`) do even win10 x64. however it was already in win2000 how minimum  ( [look](https://github.com/Safe3/WinNT4/blob/master/private/ntos/dll/ldrsnap.c#L1420) )

Comment: @RbMm Do Microsoft know that the W2K source is on github? o.O

Comment: @JonathanPotter - this question rather to microsoft, but think that know. and this "probing" not have any side-effects, except slower load times